Visibility issues at project odoo17
Actually I'm using the native functionality from odoo 17 for projects visibility, I configured in the past two private projects just for followers, this two projects are hidden for another users but now some users have been created some new projects I already modified the configuration for this new projects to private but it didnt works, every user with the role user at projects can see the projects and the the task inside, how can I solve this?

